# "Get updates" button in Windows Store (Win11 ARM) shows warning icon

Tags: windows-11, arm, windows-store

I recently setup Windows 11 (ARM) in Parallels on my M1 iMac. Everything works fine, except that the Windows Store doesn't allow me to fetch updates properly.

When I click on the **Get updates** button, the loading icon spins for a second or two before showing a Warning icon, then goes back to its default state.

The odd thing is, though, if I go to an application I know has an update I can update it via the button on its page and it'll even show up in the Library update list. And generally doing this has Windows grab updates for other programs as well (as if the **Get updates** button was working as intended).

Windows Updates, etc. all work fine. And I don't think it's a Parallels issue, as I have another Win11 ARM install on my work computer and the store works as intended there.

I recalling doing the steps to reinstall & clear the cache for the Windows Store, but no luck in fixing the issue.

Comment: Are you in the Windows Store when you click Get Updates, or are you in OS Settings?

Comment: I am in the Windows Store.